# Find a String in a .txt file

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I want to find a specific string in different .txt files which I can choose in my computer's files. This code actually works:

```
string = "example" 
fichier = open(file_path, "r")
for line in fichier:
    if string in line:
        print string
fichier.close()
```

But I have to wrote the path by myself, and when I add those code lines in order to select the file without writting the whole file's path by myself:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile
import os

Tk().withdraw()
file = askopenfile()
file_path = os.path.realpath(file)
string = "example" 
fichier = open(file_path, "r")
for line in fichier:
    if string in line:
        print string
fichier.close()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\Lib\sip-4.18.dev1603251537\fichier txt.py", line 13, in <module>
        file_path = os.path.realpath(file)
      File "C:\Users\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\ntpath.py", line 488, in abspath
        path = _getfullpathname(path)
    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

I can't see what's wrong, because the `os.path.realpath()` gives a path, right? I guess my problem comes from the `askopenfile()`, I can't find what kind of data it returned.
I would appreciate if you give me a hand please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`askopenfile()` does not return a file *name*; it returns a file *object*.  That means that you don't need to do the opening yourself. You can just do this:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile
import os

Tk().withdraw()
fichier = askopenfile()
string = "example" 
for line in fichier:
    if string in line:
        print string
fichier.close()
```

You shouldn't be using `file` as a variable name anyway, because in Python2 it shadows the built-in type.